# Find element with maximum value recursively in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, recursion, max

I would write a recursive function that take a list of number as argument and return maximum element of the list. I don't want to use `max()` function.

```
a = [2,1,3,5]
def f(a, m=0):
    if m<a[0]:
        m = a[0]
    if len(a) == 1:
        return m
    else:
        f(a[1:])

print(f(a))
```

but it returns `None`! how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define `m` in your `else` statement and add a `return` in it:

```
a = [2,1,3,5]
def f(a, m=0):
    if m<a[0]:
        m = a[0]
    if len(a) == 1:
        return m
    else:
        m = f(a[1:], m)
        return m

print(f(a))
```

Comment: Since the first branch only does what the second branch does as well, it can be eliminated entirely. ``if len(a) > 1: m = f(...)`` followed by an unguarded ``return m`` covers both cases.